# Live private broadcasting online

Tags: raspberry-pi, data-dump, ar.drone

I'd like to build a homemade land drone based in Raspberry Pi, a camera module, a WiFi module, some motors... I'd like it to be Internet-controlled, so I can use it remotely and do small tasks. It's a difficult project, but my only question is:
is there any webpage which could send live data dump between my computer and my drone?. It would work like the Parrot AR Drone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want a private one-to-one stream to go over the internet, but streaming services are generally used to provide bandwidth for one-to-many applications.

Nevertheless it will be much easier send your stream directly from your RPi to your computer. If it needs to go over internet, you should probably also configure you router to let the traffic pass.

Now your challenge will be dealing with **latency**.

You might want to search for answers on [Raspberry Pi S.E.](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

You could to this in different ways:

- TCP socket: you can use you raspberryPi as a tcp server and you can connect to it from any internet device with C++, C, java or whatever code you prefer. It is easy and very robust but you have to deal whit latency (even if it couldn't be a problem)
- HTML5 socket: in a web browser you can open an html5 socket and send data point point whit it.